# Efficient way to read contents of file based on timestamp

Tags: java, performance, bufferedreader, filereader, fileinputstream

I have a file say abc.log in which data with a timestamp is appended.

For example:

```
2018-02-18 22:42:05 DATA_ONE

2018-02-18 22:42:20 DATA_TWO

2018-02-18 22:44:05 DATA_THREE

2018-02-19 00:42:05 DATA_FOUR

2018-02-19 01:42:05 DATA_FIVE

2018-02-19 01:44:05 DATA_SIX

2018-02-19 03:42:05 DATA_SEVEN

2018-02-19 04:42:05 DATA_EIGHT

2018-02-19 06:42:05 DATA_NINE
```

What is the fastest or most efficient way to read/get only those lines with timestamp within last two hours in Java?

One way I know is to read and parse the entire file line by line and get only those lines with timestamp within last two hours, but is there any better or efficient way to do this?

NOTE: Since data is being appended to file, the file size keeps growing exponentially. Reading the entire file and parsing it every time will lead to performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can use a [Dichotomic search or binary search algoritm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

The first search is in the middle of the file.
Depending if the time is before or after the read record, the next search will be done in the first quarter, or the third quarter of the file. And so on. Each read narrows the hey stack. After you find the first record, you read the next sequentially.

To read the middle of the file you need to use a Random Access to the file.

How to determine each record depends on the structure of the file.

Comment: Is there a java program you could help me with, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the file way, you could generate a file per hour.
In this case, collecting the two last hours logs will be enough simple : it will be performed on 3 files and you would ignore logs which are not in the interval.
Rolling File Appenders of logging frameworks serve this goal.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Other alternative : store these information in a database and perform queries.
It would be more efficient if your logs grow and in addition it would also be more flexible if your requirement changes.

Comment: That's a different scenario, given the situation I need the most efficient way to do it